# The conjugacy classes of the simple group PSL(2,q)

Tags: combinatorics, finite-groups, simple-groups

If $q=p^{\alpha}$, where $p$ is a prime number, then I would like to know the number of conjugacy classes related to elements of order $p$ and $2$ in the simple group $PSL(2,q)$.